# understanding error covariance matrix in Kalman filter

Tags: control-theory, estimation, kalman-filter

I have recently started reading about Kalman filter for the very first time. I am using a pdf from MIT as a reference.(pdf link: https://web.mit.edu/kirtley/kirtley/binlustuff/literature/control/Kalman%20filter.pdf). In this they talk about minimizing the mean squared error which is nothing but trace of the error covariance matrix. However i am unable to understand what the elements of error covariance matrix actually are? As per the pdf, let $x_k \in \mathbb{R}^n $ be the actual state vector at time instant 'k'. Let $\hat{x_k'}  $ be the prior estimate and $\hat{x_k} $ be the updated estimate after measurement. Then the error covariance matrix is at time k is defined as:
$P_k=E[(x_k-\hat{x_k})(x_k-\hat{x_k})^T]$. Then they have talked about how trace of error covariance matrix gives mean squared error and we can minimize it. I am adding a screenshot from the pdf:
[screenshot from pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xd5Ow.png)
I am unable to understand what the elements $P_k$ actually are and how is it's trace the mean squared errors. This $P_k$ is defined for time 'k' then how can it give mean squared error for other time instants as shown in the image?

Comment: Do not use this resource, it is terrible. Pick any other one on the topic, it will be better than this one.

Comment: it does seem very confusing to me. I will look for other resources. Actually i was using it just for understanding the derivation of kalman gain matrix, since in other resources that i was using did not explain it's derivation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the equation in the screenshot very odd, and I work with Kalman filters quite often. Don't get too caught up on that particular equation.

The important takeaway is that the derivation of the Kalman "gain" matrix $K_k$ is based on minimizing the trace of $P_k$. The diagonal elements of $P_k$ (that are summed together in the trace) are the variances of the estimation errors for the individual elements of the state vector. For example, if element $i$ of the state vector $x_k$ was a position in meters, then entry $(P_k)_{ii}$ is the variance of the estimation error for state element $i$ (in units m$^2$). And it turns out that minimizing the sum of the estimation error variances over all the elements of the state is a good criterion for obtaining good estimates.

Comment: so to obtain the kalman gain matrix we find error covariance matrix at some time instant and since the diagonal of error covariance matrix contain variances of individual elements so minimizing them means we are trying to minimize the uncertainty in our "updated" estimate using the incorporation of "innovation" in our state estimation equation. So for  this we need an appropriate Kalman gain matrix, which we find by minimizing the trace?

Comment: @VAdarsh You have a pretty good understanding of it for just getting started. One interesting thing that can give some insight is: The computation of the estimate covariances $P_1, ..., P_k, ..., P_N$ and the Kalman gains $K_1, ..., K_k, ..., K_N$ at each time instant can be computed off-line ahead of time. That is, they do not depend on the observed data whatsoever, and only depend on the initial covariance $P_0$, and the model parameters $F, H, Q, R$. So the Kalman gains are essentially deterministic parameters that tell us how much we should weight observations vs our state transition model

Comment: is it because we can actually derive a recursive equation for $P_k$ and $P_k$ being in expression for optimal kalman gain, so kalman gain also gets a recursive equation, which can be determined by $P_0$

Comment: @VAdarsh Yes, that's pretty much it. The choice of $P_0$ is one of the most important aspects for "tuning" the filter correctly.